# How can I convert (AF36) hexadecimal to 2421 BCD?

Tags: computer-engineering, computer

How to represent numbers 10 to 15 in 2421 bcd?
The original question is this:
[image]

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Convert a hexadecimal to BCD first you have to convert the hexadecimal to decimal then we can convert decimal to BCD.

Now first take a look at how to convert decimal to BCD:

There is fix set of rule for this it is like

- 0 in decimal = 0000 BCD(2421),
- 1 in decimal = 0001 BCD(2421),
- 2 = 0010
- 3 = 0011
- 4 = 0100

Until here it is same as binary but it changes from here:

- 5 = 1011,
- 6 = 1100,
- 7 = 1101,
- 8 = 1110,
- 9 = 1111

So how BCD(2421) is converted lets see:

If we take an example of:

- $8 = 1110 = 1\times2+1\times4+1\times2+1\times0 = 8$
- $9 = 1111 = 1\times2+1\times4+1\times2+1\times1 = 9$

So the numbers here are multiplied by (2421) that's why it is called 2421 BCD.

Now then how to write 10?

- 10 = combination of 1&0 i.e. 00010000,
- 11 = 00010001 likewise.

So now to convert hexadecimal to binary:

$$\begin{align}
\text{(AF36) hexa} &= 10\times16^3+15\times16^2+3\times16^1+6\times16^0 \\
                   &= 40960+3840+48+6 \\
                   &=44854
\end{align}$$

Now convert this decimal no. 44854 into 2421 BCD

- 4=0100,
- 4=0100,
- 8=1110,
- 5=1011,
- 4=0100,

Combine them: 01000100111010110100 (option c)